# Why is the fetch function saying, that I have to use absolute urls, even if I have set a proxy?

Tags: javascript, shopify

At the moment I am coding a Shopify application. I want to fetch all the products from my store in server.js but every time it outputs a message, that says that only absolute urls are supported. A registered Webhook should get all the products inside my shop.

> Error: only absolute urls are supported

Here is my javascript (server.js)

```
const { default: proxy } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy');
const { ApiVersion } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy');

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = new Koa();
    const router = new Router();
    server.use(session(server));
    server.keys = [/** Shopify Keys */];

    server.use(
        createShopifyAuth({
        /**
         * Webhook
         */
        }),
    );

    const webhook = receiveWebhook({ secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY });
    router.post('/webhooks/products/create', webhook, async (ctx) => {
        await fetch('/graphql', {
            credentials: 'include',
            body: allProducts
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })

        console.log('received Webhook: ', ctx.state.webhook);
    })

    server.use(router.allowedMethods());
    server.use(router.routes());
    console.log(proxy({ version: ApiVersion.Unstable }))
    server.use(proxy({ version: ApiVersion.Unstable }))

    server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

I was using the example from the npm package shopify koa proxy link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy)

How can I send http request with the proxy I am using?

Comment: `'/webhooks/products/create'`, `'/graphql'` <= use absolute paths instead?

Comment: because `fetch` knows nothing about your proxy.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the npm package 'koa shopify graphql proxy' is using an example with fetch. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy
So I assumed it would know about the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is exactly what the error says, fetch requires absolute urls.

Whether you have a proxy or not is really irrelevant to the `fetch` api, it doesn't know about that.

Just give it an absolute URL

Comment: But why would shopify's package on npmjs.com/package/@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy use such an example? Am I missing something?